# how to get suggestions in textbox while typing text

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have text-box and grid-view is present in same asp.net page. while typing some text in `text-box` I want suggestions, if text is present in data `grid-view`.
Example: Google Suggest.

What will be the procedure to achieve this.

Comment: [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)... is there! but you have to use jQuery!

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to get this done.

Since you're using asp.net (if you're using webforms) you can use the ajax control toolkit which has a combobox control

http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx

Or you can go with jquery ui

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

There are many other plugins and frameworks you can try, but these two are pretty basic.